# Test score NaN while trying to evaluate a decision tree regressor model

Tags: python, decision-tree, scikit-learn-pipeline

I am trying to evaluate the accuracy of a decision tree model using both numerical and categorical features from the ames housing dataset. For the preprocessing of numerical features, I have used SimpleImputer and StandardScalar. As for the categorical features, I have used the one hot encoder.  I tried to evaluate the decision tree model (decision tree regressor) using 10 fold cross validation but I get Nan value for the test score. This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
ames_housing = pd.read_csv("../datasets/house_prices.csv", na_values="?")
target_name = "SalePrice"
data = ames_housing.drop(columns=target_name)
target = ames_housing[target_name]

numerical_features = [
"LotFrontage", "LotArea", "MasVnrArea", "BsmtFinSF1", "BsmtFinSF2",
"BsmtUnfSF", "TotalBsmtSF", "1stFlrSF", "2ndFlrSF", "LowQualFinSF",
"GrLivArea", "BedroomAbvGr", "KitchenAbvGr", "TotRmsAbvGrd", "Fireplaces",
"GarageCars", "GarageArea", "WoodDeckSF", "OpenPorchSF", "EnclosedPorch",
"3SsnPorch", "ScreenPorch", "PoolArea", "MiscVal",]

data_numerical = data[numerical_features]

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector as selector
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

categorical_columns = selector(dtype_include=object)(data)
numerical_columns = selector(dtype_exclude=object)(data)

preprocessor = make_column_transformer(
(OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"), categorical_columns),
(StandardScaler(), SimpleImputer(), numerical_columns),
)

model = make_pipeline(preprocessor, DecisionTreeRegressor())

cv_results = cross_validate(
model, data, target, cv=10, return_estimator=True, n_jobs=2,
)

scores = cv_results["test_score"]
print(f"Accuracy score by cross-validation "
  f"search:\n{scores.mean():.3f} +/- {scores.std():.3f}")
```

This is what I get for the test score:

```
Accuracy score by cross-validation search:
nan +/- nan
```

To find out the source of the problem, I passed (error_score='raise') as a parameter in the cross validation. As a result, the error was found out to be:

```
 ValueError: No valid specification of the columns. Only a scalar, list or slice of all integers 
  or all strings, or boolean mask is allowed
```

How do I solve this problem? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks :)

This is what my model looks like:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('columntransformer',
             ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('onehotencoder',
                                              OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'),
                                              ['MSZoning', 'Street',
                                               'Alley', 'LotShape',
                                               'LandContour', 'Utilities',
                                               'LotConfig', 'LandSlope',
                                               'Neighborhood', 'Condition1',
                                               'Condition2', 'BldgType',
                                               'HouseStyle', 'RoofStyle',
                                               'RoofMatl', 'Exterior1st',
                                               'Exterior2nd', 'MasVnrType',
                                               'ExterQual', 'ExterCond',
                                               'Foundation', 'BsmtQual',
                                               'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure',
                                               'BsmtFinType1',
                                               'BsmtFinType2', 'Heating',
                                               'HeatingQC', 'CentralAir',
                                               'Electrical', ...]),
                                             ('standardscaler',
                                              StandardScaler(),
                                              SimpleImputer())])),
            ('decisiontreeregressor', DecisionTreeRegressor())])
```

Data:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1460 entries, 0 to 1459
Data columns (total 80 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------         --------------  -----  
 0   Id             1460 non-null   int64  
 1   MSSubClass     1460 non-null   int64  
 2   MSZoning       1460 non-null   object 
 3   LotFrontage    1201 non-null   float64
 4   LotArea        1460 non-null   int64  
 5   Street         1460 non-null   object 
 6   Alley          91 non-null     object 
 7   LotShape       1460 non-null   object 
 8   LandContour    1460 non-null   object 
 9   Utilities      1460 non-null   object 
 10  LotConfig      1460 non-null   object 
 11  LandSlope      1460 non-null   object 
 12  Neighborhood   1460 non-null   object 
 13  Condition1     1460 non-null   object 
 14  Condition2     1460 non-null   object 
 15  BldgType       1460 non-null   object 
 16  HouseStyle     1460 non-null   object 
 17  OverallQual    1460 non-null   int64  
 18  OverallCond    1460 non-null   int64  
 19  YearBuilt      1460 non-null   int64  
 20  YearRemodAdd   1460 non-null   int64  
 21  RoofStyle      1460 non-null   object 
 22  RoofMatl       1460 non-null   object 
 23  Exterior1st    1460 non-null   object 
 24  Exterior2nd    1460 non-null   object 
 25  MasVnrType     1452 non-null   object 
 26  MasVnrArea     1452 non-null   float64
 27  ExterQual      1460 non-null   object 
 28  ExterCond      1460 non-null   object 
 29  Foundation     1460 non-null   object 
 30  BsmtQual       1423 non-null   object 
 31  BsmtCond       1423 non-null   object 
 32  BsmtExposure   1422 non-null   object 
 33  BsmtFinType1   1423 non-null   object 
 34  BsmtFinSF1     1460 non-null   int64  
 35  BsmtFinType2   1422 non-null   object 
 36  BsmtFinSF2     1460 non-null   int64  
 37  BsmtUnfSF      1460 non-null   int64  
 38  TotalBsmtSF    1460 non-null   int64  
 39  Heating        1460 non-null   object 
 40  HeatingQC      1460 non-null   object 
 41  CentralAir     1460 non-null   object 
 42  Electrical     1459 non-null   object 
 43  1stFlrSF       1460 non-null   int64  
 44  2ndFlrSF       1460 non-null   int64  
 45  LowQualFinSF   1460 non-null   int64  
 46  GrLivArea      1460 non-null   int64  
 47  BsmtFullBath   1460 non-null   int64  
 48  BsmtHalfBath   1460 non-null   int64  
 49  FullBath       1460 non-null   int64  
 50  HalfBath       1460 non-null   int64  
 51  BedroomAbvGr   1460 non-null   int64  
 52  KitchenAbvGr   1460 non-null   int64  
 53  KitchenQual    1460 non-null   object 
 54  TotRmsAbvGrd   1460 non-null   int64  
 55  Functional     1460 non-null   object 
 56  Fireplaces     1460 non-null   int64  
 57  FireplaceQu    770 non-null    object 
 58  GarageType     1379 non-null   object 
 59  GarageYrBlt    1379 non-null   float64
 60  GarageFinish   1379 non-null   object 
 61  GarageCars     1460 non-null   int64  
 62  GarageArea     1460 non-null   int64  
 63  GarageQual     1379 non-null   object 
 64  GarageCond     1379 non-null   object 
 65  PavedDrive     1460 non-null   object 
 66  WoodDeckSF     1460 non-null   int64  
 67  OpenPorchSF    1460 non-null   int64  
 68  EnclosedPorch  1460 non-null   int64  
 69  3SsnPorch      1460 non-null   int64  
 70  ScreenPorch    1460 non-null   int64  
 71  PoolArea       1460 non-null   int64  
 72  PoolQC         7 non-null      object 
 73  Fence          281 non-null    object 
 74  MiscFeature    54 non-null     object 
 75  MiscVal        1460 non-null   int64  
 76  MoSold         1460 non-null   int64  
 77  YrSold         1460 non-null   int64  
 78  SaleType       1460 non-null   object 
 79  SaleCondition  1460 non-null   object 
dtypes: float64(3), int64(34), object(43)
memory usage: 912.6+ KB
```

Target:

```
0       208500
1       181500
2       223500
3       140000
4       250000
         ...  
1455    175000
1456    210000
1457    266500
1458    142125
1459    147500
Name: SalePrice, Length: 1460, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what `model`, `data`, and `target` look like when printed? It sounds like you are mixing datatypes in one of them.

Comment: Hi, I have posted a sample of model, data and target in my post. I cannot post it here as I have reached the maximum number of characters in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your transformer has more than 1 estimator, in this case for numeric column, you have `StandardScaler(), SimpleImputer()` , you need to wrap it with a pipeline, for example:

```
np.random.seed(111)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,1,(100,3)),columns=['n1','n2','n3'])
data['c1'] = np.random.choice(['A','B',],100)
target = np.random.normal(0,1,100)

cat_columns = selector(dtype_include=object)(data)
num_columns = selector(dtype_exclude=object)(data)

num_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('scaler', StandardScaler()),
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer())
    ])

preprocessor = make_column_transformer(
(OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown="ignore"), cat_columns),
(num_transformer, num_columns),
)
```

Just test this on the dataset, it works:

```
preprocessor.fit_transform(data)[:2]

array([[ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.42472149, -1.23160187, -0.1782728 ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.95749076, -0.79751471, -1.12825996]])
```

Then run everything:

```
model = make_pipeline(preprocessor, DecisionTreeRegressor())

cv_results = cross_validate(
model, data, target, cv=10, return_estimator=True, n_jobs=2,
)

scores = cv_results["test_score"]

array([-2.45981423, -7.88563769, -1.15523361, -0.56772717, -0.84663734,
       -0.61938564, -3.1854688 , -1.44865232, -0.41933732, -3.13719368])
```